# can I say "bring her on" instead of "you may transfer her now"

Tags: word-choice

what is the best way of saying  "you may transfer the customer to me". Is it correct to say, "bring her on" or "send her through"

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @aneworm. 
We like [strong questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that will attract strong, definitive answers. It's not clear what you are asking in this post. Check out the [help] to learn what's on topic and how to ask strong questions.

Comment: Not if the customer might hear.  "Bring her on," in particular, suggests that the customer is a challenge and you're preparing to go into combat with her.  And "send her through" is kind of dismissive.

Comment: *I'll take it* or *connect me* or *send it through*, in reference to the call, not the caller. This may be a good question for [workplace.stackexchange](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/) where they might have better insight in telecommunication protocols.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest "Put her through".

That expression goes back to the days of mechanical switchboards when an operator would physically connect the wires required to complete the circuit that enabled the parties at each end of a call to be able to talk.